# Would a shared_ptr be materialized if I'm only calling a method on its object?

Tags: c++, std, smart-pointers

I have a trivial question on c++ `shared_ptr`s. Please consider the following pseudo code,

```cpp
class Foo{
  int run();
}

class Bar{
  // NOTE: returns a shared_ptr, not a const ref
  shared_ptr<Foo> GetFoo() const;
}

Bar bar{...};
int k = bar.GetFoo()->run();
```

in this scenario, when we call `bar.GetFoo()`, would a `shared_ptr<Foo>` be materialized (i.e. creating an atomic_counter, etc)? Or can the compiler simplify the last statement further?

Comment: if the behaviour of the code is the same the compiler might optimise away such cases, the best thing is to try it and see what happens

Comment: An implementation *may* do lots of things under the "as-if" rule, but whether the implementation you have in mind *does* can't really be answered in the abstract.

Comment: [But probably no](https://godbolt.org/z/xj94cn33j), not currently

Comment: Imagine in a multi-thread environment - if a `shared_ptr` is __not__ materialised then there is the risk of then managed `Foo` object being destroyed whilst `run()` is executing. The temporary `shared_ptr` (created on this thread) is possibly the only thing keeping it alive,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of the language require a `shared_ptr<Foo>` to be materialized even if it is immediately discarded. Calling `->run()` only affects *when* the temporary is materialized, not *whether*.

In practice, the rules about *when* the temporary is materialized are actually just rules about *who has to allocate the memory* for the temporary object to reside in. The *construction* of the temporary object occurs before `GetFoo` even returns, just like pre-C++17. This is because only `GetFoo` or one of its callees actually knows how to perform the construction (*e.g.* which arguments to pass to the `shared_ptr` constructor).

All that being said, the materialization can be elided only if the compiler can prove that it doesn't change the observable behaviour of the program. Since `shared_ptr` is fairly complicated (it has a control block with atomic counters as you seem to be aware of) it is unlikely that the compiler can prove this. Indeed, even when the definition of the function that creates the `shared_ptr` resides in the same translation unit, it [appears](https://godbolt.org/z/d6Y37f3da) that the initialization and destruction of the `shared_ptr` object are simply inlined, not elided.

Comment: The `shared_ptr::use_count` is externally visible and affected by the existence of the temporary, so the likelihood of provable unobservability is even lower.